# Setting the order of LINQ to SQL ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

I have a ComboBox at the top of a DataGrid that is bound to an observable collection from a LINQ to SQL mapping.  That is I used the "drag and drop" method to get a table into my DataClasses and then I populate an ObservableCollection.  I want to have the combobox present the items in a newest first order (which would be descending on the name field) but can't find any property to set.  It seems like sorting the observable collection is the wrong way to do it.  I am thinking that the easiest way would be to use a stored procedure instead of the table as the LINQ to SQL class generator.  Am I missing some easier built-in solution?

Here is the class code for adding the LINQ generated table to my observable collection:

```
class ObservableTransmittals : ViewableCollection<Transmittal>
{
    public ObservableTransmittals(DataClasses1DataContext dataDc) 
    {
        foreach (Transmittal trn in dataDc.Transmittals)
        {
            this.Add(trn);
        }

    }
}
```

and from below have now got it working with this:

```
class ObservableTransmittals : ViewableCollection<Transmittal>
{
    public ObservableTransmittals(DataClasses1DataContext dataDc) 
    {
        var linq = dataDc.Transmittals.OrderByDescending(x => x.TransName);
        foreach (Transmittal trn in linq)
        {
            this.Add(trn);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LINQ to Sql

```
var linq = YourTable.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToObservableCollection();
```

where ToObservableCollection is a custom extension method.

E.g.

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
  return new ObservableCollection<T>(list);
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to auto add to context or remove, you will need to listen to the CollectionChanged event of base class.

```
class ObservableTransmittals : ObservableCollection<Transmittal>
{
    private readonly YourContext _dataContext;

    public ObservableTransmittals(YourContext dataContext)
    {

        var linq = dataContext.Transmittals.OrderByDescending(x => x.TransName);
        foreach (Transmittal trn in linq)
        {
            this.Add(trn);
        }

        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        _dataContext.Transmittals.Remove(this[index]);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Transmittal item)
    {
        _dataContext.Transmittals.Add(item);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, Transmittal item)
    {
        // Add replace logic
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: So instead of the foreach loop that I use now (see my edit above), I could instead further extend my viewable collection (which exposes a filterable list method) to include this extension method . . . I'm not sure but will try.

Comment: Ah yes . . . Thanks for the insight . . . just added the var linq line in front of my for each loop, and then used linq in the foreach loop instead of the linq Table as before.  Very nice.

Comment: Since I am just using this as a filtering tool the binding back to the database is not imperative.  But I am thinking that this perhaps will break the binding back to the database if it was to change (ie, update/delete/inserts) . . . is that correct?  Are the items in my observable collection no references to the model?

Comment: What do you mean by delete/inserts? As in if you remove an object from the collection will it get deleted/inserted?

Comment: The updates will work, as the ObservableCollecitons hold your entities, but no it will not automatically insert records into database or delete from them